# Flood Fill recursive stack overflow

Tags: c++, recursion, stack, stack-overflow, fill

If i try to Fill a 100x100 rectangle then i get an overflow. 
A 50x50 works fine.

Is there a way to fix the overflow?

I also print out the Stack Number and sometimes the working rectangle Stack is higher then the big one (it crashes around 7000).

```
void draw(int x, int y)
{
if ((x >= 0 && x < 100) && (y >= 0 && y < 100))
    {
            canvas.set_pixel(x, y);
            if (!canvas.get_pixel(x, y + 1))draw(x, y + 1);
            if (!canvas.get_pixel(x, y-1))draw(x, y - 1);
            if (!canvas.get_pixel(x - 1, y))draw(x - 1, y);
            if (!canvas.get_pixel(x+1, y))draw(x + 1, y);   

    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're running out of stack

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get a stack overflow is that the recursion goes too deep.

How deep will it go? Well, with the algorithm the way you designed it - it will actually go to depth `100*100=10,000`!

Let's look at in what order will the canvas be filled - assuming the canvas is empty and we start filling from the middle:

- set the middle pixel
- go to x,y+1
- do that until you get to the edge
- at the edge - move to x-1,0 (remember, we're at the top)
- go down until the bottom

etc. etc.

The point is - you're going deeper and deeper until you fill the canvas, and then have a "chain" of recursion calls going all around the canvas and it's a waste :)

Benjamin is right that you can use a stack, but a stack basically does the exact same thing (just without the recursion), so the stack will get to depth 10,000 as well. Still a waste, and you run out of memory in some cases (for a bitmap canvas, each pixel takes 1 bit, but the stack will have 2 integers per pixel for `x,y`, and thus could take 64 times more memory than the canvas)

Instead - use a queue! Almost the same code:

```
void draw(int x, int y)
{
    struct coordinate { int x, y; };
    std::queue<coordinate> to_draw; // <- changed from stack to queue
    to_draw.push({x, y});

    while (!to_draw.empty())
    {
        auto top = to_draw.front(); // <- changed from top to front
        to_draw.pop();
        if (  (top.x >= 0 && top.x < 100)
           && (top.y >= 0 && top.y < 100)
           && !canvas.get_pixel(top.x, top.y))
        {
            canvas.set_pixel(top.x, top.y);
            to_draw.push({top.x, top.y + 1});
            to_draw.push({top.x, top.y - 1});
            to_draw.push({top.x + 1, top.y});
            to_draw.push({top.x - 1, top.y});
        }            
    }
}
```

And now the memory needed will be `<=4*100`! In other words - by changing from stack to queue we changed the memory needed from `N*N` to `4*N`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it sounds very nice but is there a way to do it recursive?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use recursion. Instead, use a stack to store the coordinates you want to draw. And iterate until the stack is empty.

```
void draw(int x, int y)
{
    struct coordinate { int x, y; };
    std::stack<coordinate> to_draw;
    to_draw.push({x, y});

    while (!to_draw.empty())
    {
        auto top = to_draw.top();
        to_draw.pop();
        if (  (top.x >= 0 && top.x < 100)
           && (top.y >= 0 && top.y < 100)
           && !canvas.get_pixel(top.x, top.y))
        {
            canvas.set_pixel(top.x, top.y);
            to_draw.push({top.x, top.y + 1});
            to_draw.push({top.x, top.y - 1});
            to_draw.push({top.x + 1, top.y});
            to_draw.push({top.x - 1, top.y});
        }            
    }
}
```